# Extracting the content value of a Key in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to be able to get the "Content" value of the following buttons without having to write a function for each one of them. I have the following function that I want to use for all the buttons.

```
private void Window_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetViewModel(e.OriginalKey.ToString());
    }
```

this is the XAML code for the button and I want the Content value to be passed to the SetViewModel() function.

```
<Button x:Name="btn4"  Content="4" Margin="0,5,0,0" Click="btn4_Click" KeyUp ="Window_KeyUp"/>
<Button x:Name="btn5"  Content="5" Margin="5,5,0,0" Click="btn5_Click" KeyUp ="Window_KeyUp"/>
<Button x:Name="btn6"  Content="6" Margin="5,5,0,0" Click="btn6_Click" KeyUp ="Window_KeyUp"/>
```

Comment: you can get the content using((sender as button).Content).ToString(), also you can add Button.KeyUp="Window_KeyUp" in the parent layout panel of the buttons(Grid,StackPanel...).

Answer (score 3):

Since you know that your event handling function is called from a `Button` in each case, you should be able to cast the `sender` parameter to `Button` an then access the `Content` property.

```
var content = ((Button)e).Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Martin give you the right way, I rewrite your code:

```
private string Window_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;//get the button who rised the KeyUp event
        string str = btn.Content;//get the property in a string
        return str;//I replace return type from void to string in your code, this is why I return a string
    }
```

The 2 last lines can be rewrite like this:

```
return btn.Content;
```